# Include tag along with other tagless tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, command-line, rspec

Right now I rspec configured so that running the `rspec` command by itself excludes any tests that require loading the Rails environment:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run_excluding :type => 'feature'
end
```

The excluded tests look like the following:

```
describe 'Feature that requires rails', :type => :feature do
  # test, test, test
end
```

The command `rspec -t type:feature` will run these tests **exclusively**.

With this configuration, is there a way to run **all** tests in one command, **including** the feature tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I accomplish this is to use an environment variable so changing what you have to:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run_excluding :type => 'feature' unless ENV["ALLOW_FEATURES"]
end
```

and then running your tests with:

```
ALLOW_FEATURES=true rspec
```

will ignore the exclude and run all tests